# Difference spacy's "--base-model" and "--vectors" arguments for using custom embeddings for NER?

Tags: python, spacy, fasttext

I trained fasttext embeddings and saved them as a `.vec` file.
I want to use these for my spacy NER model. Is there a difference between

`python -m spacy train en [new_model] [train_data] [dev_data] --pipeline ner --base-model embeddings.vec`

and

`python -m spacy train en [new_model] [train_data] [dev_data] --pipeline ner --vectors embeddings.vec`
?

Both methods produce nearly identical training loss, F score, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to initialize a spacy model with vectors, use `spacy init-model` like this where `lg` is the language code:

```sh
spacy init-model lg model_dir -v embeddings.vec -vn my_custom_vectors
```

Once you have the vectors saved as part of a spacy model:

- `--vectors` loads the vectors from the provided model, so the initial model is `spacy.blank("lg")` + vectors
- `--base-model` loads everything (tokenizer, pipeline components, vectors) from the provided model, so the initial model is `spacy.load(model)`

If the provided model doesn't have any pipeline components in it, the only potential difference is the tokenizer settings resulting from `spacy.blank("lg")` which can vary a little between individual spacy versions.